# Fetch Azure role assignments to AAD groups

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-role-environment

In our current azure tenant we have 100's of subscriptions, user access is managed by azure AAD groups.

How can i view roles assigned to a group, Assume 1 group had access to only 1 subscription out of 100 subscriptions then from portal i need to select each and every subscription in group Azure role assignment page.

I wonder is there any direct way to fetch using powershell?

Thanks
dev

Comment: @CarlZhao Thanks for the reply..link you have provide is related to exchange not related to azure AAD groups

Comment: Hi, If you still have any doubts, I will answer you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we use the `Get-AzRoleAssignment` command to list all the role assignments that are valid on the scope. If no parameters are specified, this command will return all the role assignments made under the subscription.

For your problem, you want to use a security group to filter this list, just use the Azure AD group ObjectId parameter:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId  <your group objectid>
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. In MS Graph API docs there is `List appRoleAssignments granted to a group` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/api/group-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
2. Test it under MS Graph
3. You can use `Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK` https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell
4. Here are samples code - for example for fetching groups:
   https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/tree/dev/samples